# How to pass command line parameters(pretty much like flashvars) to flashplayer.exe?

Tags: flash, command-line-arguments

Anyone knows the trick?

I googled but found no such solution yet.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered **Adobe Air**, if it's a *desktop* Flash app?

[This third party Flash tool](http://www.flashjester.com/index.php?section=faq_search&search=command%20line#250) seems to do the trick.

Another possibility, is to use `_root.loadVariables("some\path\to\myvars.txt")`
myvars.txt:

```
xVar=xVal&yVar=yVal&zVar=zVal
```

Or, you could embed the flash with COM [as explained here for .NET](http://weblogs.asp.net/twalters/archive/2003/12/29/46265.aspx).